# Scalable java web APP openshift - 503 error HAProxy

Tags: java, maven, openshift, haproxy

I started create a new java web application scalable, but is not working, since i got error
"503 Service Unavailable No server is available to handle this request".
Im using RESTful service

My code is:

TestClass

> @Path("/test")

```
public class TestClass {

    @GET
    public String getName() {
        return "John";
    }
}
```

web.xml

> 

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">

    <!-- Auto scan REST service -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

pom

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>myApp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>myApp</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>myApp</finalName>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>myApp</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

In my Haproxy.cfg, i have this line option httpchk GET /myApp
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have something in your application listening on the root context (/) then the haproxy will see your application as being down.  You either need to have something listen on the root context, or change the monitoring option to point to a url that is returning a 200 (success) when it is polled.

Did you change the httpchk GET / to the httpchk GET /myApp?

Even if you change your application to be deployed at /myApp, you still need something that gives a 200 success on that url.

Comment: so maybe if i change my httpchk GET /myApp to httpchk GET /myApp/test, should work ,right?

Comment: if you have something responding on /myApp/test, then yes. It could even be as simple as adding a check.html file that it checks to make sure your application is up.

Comment: Well, like you see on my class "TestClass", i returned a String. Should be a file? Cant be a string or object?

Comment: I have been getting the 503 error from times to times, sadly I haven't been able to find the root cause.  so far it seems that openshift stops all request to the servlet and just throw that 503 when I use a lot of ram